# Explain the process of formation of word senses in WordNet

Tags: natural-language-processing

Regarding the word sense disambiguation problem, read the following fact  written on [Knowledge-based Word Sense Disambiguation using Topic Models](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dchaplot/papers/aaai18_wsd_tm.pdf):

> Note that although WordNet is the most widely used sense repository, the sense distinctions can be too ﬁne-grained in many scenarios. This makes it difﬁcult for expert annotators to agree on a correct sense, resulting in a **very low inter-annotator agreement (72%) in standard WSD datasets**.

I would like to understand better the process of assignment of a sense to a word but there is no detailed explanation at the web.

Can somebody here give some examples of cases which are hard to find a sense using WordNet?